# Change of artifactId Selenium-java.jar from 3.3.1 to 3.4 causing a ton of 'can not be accessed' errors in my maven project

Tags: maven, selenium, m2eclipse, selenium3

We are running a Selenium 3.3.1 project with many dependencies(given in a pom.xml file) as part of a maven project. Only when we change the version of artifactId Selenium-java from 3.3.1 to 3.4, all started crumbling. 
A ton of 'not accessible' errors came up for By, Select, Keys etc. kind of regular Selenium classes. Some other classes like WebDriver, WebElement etc are resolving just fine.
No matter whether we clean,build,install the Maven project the errors won't go away. I even removed the entire .m2 folder and refreshed the project, for no avail.
When I either moved back to artifactId version 3.3.1 or go to a higher version 3.12.0, every thing compiles just fine.
Is there any particular problem with artifactId Selenium-java 3.4.0? I am using Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: Thanks @Harinder for your response.
Thanks for you reply. We did exactly that only. See below.<dependency>
  **<org.seleniumhq.selenium.version>3.4.0</org.seleniumhq.selenium.version>**


                   _<dependency>
   '<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>${org.seleniumhq.selenium.version}</version>
  </dependency>_

Answer (score 1):

try with below dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and referh the project.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. We did exactly that only. See below.<dependency>
  <org.seleniumhq.selenium.version>3.4.0</org.seleniumhq.selenium.version>

   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>${org.seleniumhq.selenium.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Thank dude. No one said refresh the project.